# Functions that Register and Show WordPress List Tables

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing my own plugin and I am trying to figure out how to add WordPress List Tables to my admin page. I am aware I can write the the HTML myself but if there is an API method this is the most desirable.

An example are `Meta Postboxes`; I can easily write my own markup and have the postbox collapse and show but its much better to use the API function `add_meta_box()` and `do_meta_boxes()`.

My searching hasn't come up with any functions that create lists/tables like the ones below. What are the API functions that allow me to register and show WordPress List Tables?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To add Bulk actions

Bulk action are implemented by overwriting the method `get_bulk_actions()` and returning an associated array:

```
function get_bulk_actions() {
  $actions = array(
    'delete'    => 'Delete'
  );
  return $actions;
}
```

I have write a blog on how to create WP_List_Table.
You can check out ** [WP_List_Table - a step by step guide](http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/)**

You can check this link for more information  : http://wpengineer.com/2426/wp_list_table-a-step-by-step-guide/